# paraphrase on overloading of builtin operators

Tags: c++

Refer to here:
http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1

The last sentence in that paragraphs goes like this:

> If there is a user-written candidate with the same name and parameter types as a built-in candidate operator function, the built-in operator function is hidden and is not included in the set of candidate functions.

I cannot write a function definition with signature such as `int operator+(int, int)` at the first place, so regarding the `operator+`, what will be the custom functions mentioned in the above quoted sentence?

Comment: Nobody said it had to be `+`. There are other operators.

Comment: @EJP  That's why I use the phrase `such as'.